# What it would look like to observe people with a different time flows?

Tags: special-relativity, gravity, mass, spacetime, time

As I learned, that the bigger gravity source you are influenced by the more slow time ticks for you, the farther away you are from a gravity source the faster times ticks.

So Imagine two different planets where on each people live, one planet is massively big (time ticks slow), the other one very small comparatively (time ticks faster).
How would it look like for bigger planet people to observe smaller planet and for smaller planet people to observe them.
Hope it makes some sense.

Comment: [Cross-posted on Astronomy](http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/8136/what-it-would-look-like-to-observe-people-with-a-different-time-flows). Please don't do this.

Answer (score 2):

It depends upon how they observed each other and upon their relative movement.

If the people on each plant took a video of themselves and sent the recording to the other planet, the people watching the video on the other planet would not notice any difference in the passage of time.

If the people observed each other through powerful telescopes, then assuming the two planets were stationary relative to each other, the people on the bigger planet would seem to be slowed down according to the people on the smaller planet, and vice versa.

If the planets were moving, the appearance would depend upon the Doppler effect too, speeding the images up if the planets were approaching each other, and slowing the images down if the planets were moving apart.

Answer (score 1):

The people on the larger planet would marvel at how quickly those on the smaller planet got things done.

Those on the small planet would marvel at how long those on the larger planet live.

Answer (score 0):

Em, it will be no "image deformation" if your question is about it, just the biggest mass of the big planet will more curves the space time around it and the light will need more time to escape the big planet since the space time curvature will induce a longer distance for the light to travel throught.